# How to load an image based on 'onclick event'

Tags: javascript, html

I am creating an interactive and I have three colours on a page as divs. Once the user clicks on a colour, I want the image to load on the next section as the colour that is selected by the user. I have created three png's of jackets in different colours and I need to know how to load the colour of the jacket depending on what option they select.

```
<div id="page-colour">
    <h1>About your jacket.</h1>
    <h2>Select your leather jacket colour.</h2>
        <div class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-2">
            <div class="black-button colourButton">
                <p>Black</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-2">                  
            <div class="brown-button colourButton">
                <p>Brown</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-2">                  
            <div class="white-button colourButton">
                <p>White</p>
            </div>
        </div>

</div>

<div id="page-build">

   <div class="theJacket col-xs-3 col-md-9">
        <img class="" src="img/black-jacket.png" class="img-responsive" alt="Black Leather Jacket" width="600" height="750"/>
    </div>

</div>
```

This is how I have been loading the next page:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.intro-button').click(function(){
        transition("#page-jacket","fade");
    });


function transition(toPage, type){
    var toPage = $(toPage),
        fromPage = $("#pages .current"); // store the page that is currently showing

    toPage
    .addClass("current " + type + " in")
    .one("msAnimationEnd animationend oAnimationEnd", function(){  // listens for when the animation has finished
      fromPage.removeClass("current " + type + " out" );
      toPage.removeClass(type + " in");
    });
  fromPage.addClass(type + " out ");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are various ways to do this. One obvious way is to store the image url in an extra data element in the jacket div:

```
<div class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-2">
    <div class="black-button colourButton" data-imageurl="img/black-jacket.png">
        <p>Black</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then you update your script so then when a visitor clicks on a jacket colour, the image is refreshed:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.colourButton').on('click', function () {
     $('.theJacket img').attr('src', $(this).data('imageurl'));
  });
});
```

or give the image an ID and call it directly by its ID instead of via `.theJacket img`

Plnkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/McyGeEv1o8ysf9ruj8cr?p=preview

Comment: That works perfect, thanks!
Do you know of a way I can load it on the next page? so instead of loading under the list of colours, but after I have loaded the page using: 

 $('.colourButton').click(function(){
  transition("#page-build","fade");
 });

Comment: Nice, glad I could help.